# How to record audio so that it overwrites the beginning of the recording once it reaches a specific length?

Tags: java, android, audio, recording

I have been pondering this for a few days now, but i cant figure out the best way of doing it.
I want to be able to record Audio for 2 min (for example), and once it reaches that length, i want it to start deleteing the beginning of the recording so as to keep the audio file at the same length as it continues recording.

I was thinking maybe doing it so once it reaches a specific length, it starts deleting 1 second segments of the audio or something.
but i am really not sure what to do.

Does anyone have any idea of the best way of accomplishing the above, so that it keeps recording, but keeps the audio file at a specific length?.

Thanks in advance

Cheers
Corey

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Java or Android question. Can you narrow down what you're wanting?

Comment: Hi, i am creating a android app (hence the android and java tags). I want to be able to continuously record audio with the app, but only save the last x minutes, so it goes around in a loop, but it always keeps the x amount of the recording saved (so it doesnt just record 10 mins, then restart from 0, and record 10 min again). i hope i am making my self clear. Thanks Corey

Answer (score 1):

How about this: You record into two files, each containing x minutes (x == 2 in your case). You start recording into the first file, switch to the second after x minutes, and then switch back and forth until stop. Then, you concatenate the two files in the correct order and cut out the last x minutes, throw away those two temporary files.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i will try what you said, and see if it works. Thanks again, Cheers Corey

Comment: @Fishingfon have you done that.please give me some guide for this task.
 thank you in advance